# What is override point for dismissing modal view controller with page curl transition

Tags: ios5

I'm displaying a view controller modally via a storyboard segue.  The transition style is page curl.  I have a done button on the modal view controller that is set up to use a delegate to return data to the parent view controller.  All of that works fine.

However, I note it is possible to return to the parent view controller by tapping on the page curl itself. I am trying to figure out how to get my code to execute when the user dismisses via tapping the page curl.

Overriding dismissModalViewControllerAnimated did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"unwindFromCodeStatus:" sender:nil];
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208869/1705353
}
```

Works but generates a warning

Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller [YourViewController: 0x8997930] while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!