# How to trigger a unwind segue using alerts xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboardsegue

We are currently working on an Xcode project and we would like to put a notification before triggering an unwind segue. Not sure how to do this. We have tried shouldperformsegue function, but it didn't really work.

Anyone has an idea of how to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to unwind, on UIAlertView dismissal or something?

Comment: Yes, we want to unwind when UIAlertView is dismissed.

Comment: Ok, have a look on this link:  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208869/2458651)