# UIWebView: Sending data back to previous controller using unwind segues without button

Tags: ios, uiwebview, http-status-code-404, unwind-segue

Say, for instance I have a UIWebview. If I get the status code of 404, then I want to return some data to the previous view controller so that it knows to refresh the list of webpages.

I heard about `unwind segues`. However, everything that I have found on this sounds like it has to be implemented via a storyboard button.

Is there anyway to perform an unwind segue just in code. Meaning if I find this error - then set some kind of variable to the previous view controller so that it knows how to handle the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try searching before ask, this is already answered on here:

[How to perform Unwind segue programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically)

Look at Vadim and Dean answers

Comment: I did do research before asking. But, my question was specifically without a button. Everything I had found was with a button. 

Thank you for the link!