# Unwind Push Segue from UITableViewCell tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unwind-segue

I'm trying to unwind a push segue when the user taps a UITableViewCell, but the main issue is how can I make an unwind segue to perform if I cant physically make it in interface builder. I have tried dragging from the Orange Viewcontroller square to the red Exit square and naming that segue and trying to call [self performSegueWithID: -----] etc. and it does nothing.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: In which class have you implemented the `IBAction` method for the unwind segue?  It needs to be in the destination class

Comment: I dont have an IBAction method for the unwind segue because I dont have any button etc. to attach it to

Comment: You don't need to attach it to a button.  You need to define an IBAction method that accepts a UIStoryboardSegue in your destination class.  Then when you drag to the exit box you will see this method as a selection.  Once you have the unwind segue in place and named you can use performSegue to invoke it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically