# how to present active UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a barButtonItem and I am performing an action from that to show another viewController(first in hierarchy), but it gets hard, cause if I try

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```

it gets me not that viewController, that I need.
also, if I am doing

```
    var navigCont = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationViewController)
    navigCont.navigationBar.barTintColor = instaColor
    navigCont.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigCont.navigationBar.translucent = false
    navigCont.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it gets error, cause

```
Application tried to present modally an active controller
```

So I am stucked, and I don't know how to present my VC right. Any advices?

Comment: I think you need  Add More Details About your Problem ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was simply to create segue and make action for this segue in storyboard. The goal was - create a sequel without a storyboard item.
Actually this isn't a correct answer on my question, but this way of solving helped.

[How to perform Unwind segue programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to present `destinationViewController` on a navigation controller with rootViewController set to `destinationViewController` itself. 
Create a new `rootViewController` for your `navigationController` and try below code if it works:

```
var mainViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "MainViewController", bundle: nil)
var navigCont = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
navigCont.navigationBar.barTintColor = instaColor
navigCont.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navigCont.navigationBar.translucent = false
navigCont.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```