# unwind segue programatically (back to root view controller from table view cell selection)

Tags: objective-c

I m new to storyboard, in my application i have story board with name "LeftMenuList" in this i have created table view controller manually and place table view to self.view, now i wan't unwind segue from table view cell selection for root view controller.

For this i read multiple document related to unwind segue.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc8Ez9YfBSM
2. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/    etc..

but in every document button's are created using storyboard and  for connection just cntr+drag from button to exit.

But as i said earlier my table view is created manually so i m not able connect selected cell to exit for creating unwind segue (go back to login view), so can any buddy help me how can i solved my issue..For more clarification i will attach screen shot.

[image: Root View Controller -Login Screen -- Click on submit button-- VC2 open]

[image: on top left corner there is on button like option on click of this left menu list will open]

[image: LeftMenuList view controller is story board view but table view created manually, now i want to go back to root view controller on table view cell selection.]

Code :---

1) In Viewcontroller.m (root View-Login Screen) added below method as i wan't this view on unwind segue:-

```
-(IBAction)UnwindSegueToRootViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}
```

2) In leftMenuList.m (in this view controller i m having table view cell on-- cell selection(logout) need to go back login screen -- so below is didSelectRowAtIndexPath)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.strSelectedOption = [self.arrOfMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self.strSelectedOption isEqualToString:@"Logout"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindSegueToRootViewController" sender:self];
//        [self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindSegueToRootViewController" sender:self];

    }

}
```

And below Screen shot shows identifier connection

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically

Comment: Hi kevin, Thank you for comment, as i created sample demo as per ur suggested link it's working fine for me,but when ever i m trying to implement in main project it throws an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LeftMenuList: 0x7b9908a0>) has no segue with identifier 'UnwindSegueToRootViewController''
*** First throw call stack:"

Comment: /Users/giftechnologiesmac2/Desktop/1.tiff , in my view controller ---(IBAction)UnwindSegueToRootViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    
}  and in leftmenulist--table view --- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.strSelectedOption = [self.arrOfMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    if ([self.strSelectedOption isEqualToString:@"Logout"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindSegueToRootViewController" sender:self];
       
    }
        
}

Comment: Could you post your code in the question above to make it easier to see what is going on?

Comment: hi kevin please check , i have added my code.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debug print command in your if statement "if ([self.strSelectedOption isEqualToString:@"Logout"])" to see if you are actually getting the right cell value back?  As far as I can see the unwind Segue looks OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75811/discussion-between-kevin-horgan-and-spypriyanka).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Resolved my issue.. For this i have created one delegate method of left menu class