# To customize Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, unwind-segue

I am beginner in iOS. I tried unwind segue in if condition. The problem is simple. That is, "If Condition yes, unwind segue should work. else the unwind segue should not work." Kindly answer me for this problem.

Comment: You may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509422/how-to-perform-unwind-segue-programmatically for detailed information on this issue. Hope it is not very difficult for you to follow...

Comment: thanks. I got answer