# How to daisy multiple UIViewController transitions together during unwind

Tags: ios, uikit

Consider this modal stack

```
A <-> B <-> C
  \--------/\
```

A can present B or C.
Whenever I need to leave C I need to end up on B,
which means if I got to C from view controller B I can just dismiss.
If I got to C directly from A then I need to unwind back to A and present B.
Bonus points if the latter case can be animated as C -> B transition bypassing the show of controller A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single function to dismiss all open view controllers swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520899/single-function-to-dismiss-all-open-view-controllers-swift)

Comment: I has nothing to do with plain unwind. controller B has to be presented on the (modal) stack after the unwind will have completed.