# How to dismiss message app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

Can you see that here : https://vimeo.com/279403383

I'm trying present a passcode view. Because this app is sensitive to security.

So if app did enter background, request passcode.

In this case pretty well work.

But, specific case work oddly.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            guard let passcodeManageView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "passcodeManageView") as? PasscodeManageViewController else { return }
            passcodeManageView.state = State.loginMode
            passcodeManageView.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

            var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            while let presentController = rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
                rootViewController = presentController
            }
            rootViewController?.present(passcodeManageView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

So, my question is

1. How does passcode view cover MFMessageComposeViewController?
2. or How to dismiss MFMessageComposeViewController?

What is the best way???

Comment: To dismiss any (modal) view controller, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520899/single-function-to-dismiss-all-open-view-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the presented ViewControllers of your app and 
close them one by one.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {  
    if let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
      var  presented = rootViewController.presentedViewController
      while presented != nil
      {
        if presented is MFMessageComposeViewController {
          rootViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
          break
        } else {
           presented = presented?.presentedViewController
        }
      }

    }

    guard let passcodeManageView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "passcodeManageView") as? PasscodeManageViewController else { return }
    passcodeManageView.state = State.loginMode
    passcodeManageView.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

    var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let presentController = rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
      rootViewController = presentController
    }
    rootViewController?.present(passcodeManageView, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: You see my video?? I can't create MFMessageComposeViewController. Because it's automatic create by apple's framework message app. If you does not understand my reply, you should see my video.

Comment: I watched your video. Can you share the code where you trigger the message app?

Comment: just activity controller is trigger. like this.

Comment: let message = "string..."
                let actController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message], applicationActivities: nil)
                self.present(actController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: check my modified answer

Comment: I'll check this.

Comment: your modified answer is working that case. but I don't want whole presented view dismiss...just dismiss MFMessageComposeViewController...

Comment: What you need is simple if you are able to dismiss all the presented views. Just check for the `MFMessageComposerViewController` class and only dismiss that view

Comment: I see your answer. your answer dismiss MFMessageViewController. So, Where should I write present passcode view??

Comment: just add your existing code after the MFMessageViewController been dismissed. see updated answer.