# what is the correct way to be back to first view controller if not using navigation controller?

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

[image]

I have case that I can't use navigation controller, I want to back from YellowVC to blueVC. if using navigation controller I usually use

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

but If I don't use navigation controller I find there is two way to back from blueVC to yellowVC.

1. using unwind segue
2. using present modally like the picture below

[image]

so what is the best way to back to first view controller? using unwind segue or using present modally segue?

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520899/single-function-to-dismiss-all-open-view-controllers

Comment: Use an unwind segue

Comment: How to moved from blue to yellow view-controller. Are you using present modally for moving from blue to red and then red to yellow?

Comment: then start using navigation-controller – you cannot do better _all of the jobs_ what the nav-controller does / offers (you may not be even aware of those jobs what happens behind the scene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are presenting all views, better way is to use unwind Segues.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it will be easy if you use dismiss view controller.

- you just have to pass any uniq value to the second view controller class when the back button of third VC class.(any string or any integer)
- and just check the value with a if condition in the view did load of second VC class then if its matches dismiss the current VC(second VC) thats enough.

**3VC class**

```
@IBAction func back_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    2_vcObject.String = "skip2" 
    }
```

**2Vc Class**

```
view did load()

 if string == "skip2"
{
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) 
}
```