# Swift - Viewcontrollers not deinit when segue is performed

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, deinit

I am fairly new to the whole concept of memory management and ARC.

I've recently looked into it and found mixed success.

Firstly it should be noted that ***some*** `ViewController` do deinitialize but I am still learning and cleaning up my application.

However, a common pattern I have noticed is that when I use the line `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` this does infact `deinit` a view controller, given if there are no strong references.

However, my issue is that when I use a segue and use `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail_Segue", sender: nil)` the `deinit` method is never used/called. (I just have a print statement to indicate whether a view has been deinitalized). In most cases, when I perform a segue, I am passing data to another view controller and as a result, I use the following function `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {}`.

I have tried to change my segue to `navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)` but my application crashes.

Am I missing something here?

The `ViewControllers` that deinitliaze when the `navigationController` is `popped` also do not deinitialze when performing a `segue` programmatically.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your performSegue method. My guess would be you're unintentionally creating a strong reference there.

Comment: My `perfomSegue` method is like this `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "details_Segue" {
            let detailsVC = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            let text = sender as! String
            detailsVC.textDescription = text
        }
    }`

Comment: I reread your question and I think I might have understood it wrongly. Lemme type put an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an unwind segue for returning to a previous ViewController. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27463286/1630618) for how to create and programmatically call an unwind segue.

Comment: @vacawama Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, if I understood you correctly, you might have a misunderstanding on how segues work

**Segues cannot be used to go back to the previous viewController in stack**

This is pretty important. If you use segues as a way of going back instead of using `popViewController` you're creating a new instance of the viewController you go back to so `deinit` is never called since the viewController is still in memory.

Essentially, something like this List -> Details -> List, where you just created another instance of the list with the segue.

Comment: I am performing segues to go to a separate view controller. Some segues are to a `ViewController` in a different `UIStoryboard`. In essence I'm doing this Home -> Product -> Details. Maybe I have a misunderstanding of `deinit`. I'm trying to deallocate memory whenever a new `ViewController` is presented. This only works when I use `popViewController`.

Comment: No, the viewController you're going from is not going to deinit, since it's not being removed from the memory. Deinit works only when the controller is destroyed, and memory released - you wouldn't want this for something you need to come back to later.

Comment: segues *can* be used to go back, but you need to use an *unwind segue*.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `performSegue` and this segue is a push to another VC you are creating a new instance of VC, but your navigation stack is still the same  you only add the VC to the stack.

**Remember:**

Stack: [root, vc1, vc2]

vc2.performSegue (push)

Stack: [root, vc1, vc2, vc3]

The class only call the `denit` when you are dismissing a VC.

I Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to "dismiss" a view controller, just before/after I've performed a segue?

Comment: If you are dismissing another view controller that is not performing a segue, probably yes.